# How to skew an image in jquery instead of decreasing width?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to play around with an image gallery.

I have an issue where i cannot skew images. The image div reduces in width and the content is lost. What i want is the image to be skewed instead or cropped.

Check the fiddle to see what i mean. Also note that this probably can be done in CSS, however this is part of something bigger so I need a jQuery solution only.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FJYJM/3/)

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider li').animate({
        width: 150 + 'px'
    }, 1500);

});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want the end result to be. Your description above doesn't seem to match your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to target `#slider li img` instead of `#slider li`. You want the *image* resized and not the container (otherwise the container is going to crop since the image overlaps).

The other option is to specify a CSS style to make the `img` proportional to its container:

```
#slider li img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

As demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/Ug3Dk/ & http://jsfiddle.net/Ug3Dk/1/

Comment: Perfect, this is what i wanted. I dont know how i missed out on this

Answer (score 1):

Do you want get such effect? http://jsfiddle.net/FJYJM/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#slider li img').animate({width: 150}, 1500 );
});
```

1. Animate image, but not container
2. Set width and height values for each image